# Why this 415 response in a post, mvc test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

Hopefully someone can help. I've been following this [online resource][1], attempting to write an integration test for a RestController:

```
@Test
public void obfiscated() throws Exception {
    SearchRequest autoCompleteSearchrequest = new SearchRequest();
    autoCompleteSearchrequest.setCity("somewheresville");
```

Comment: What is `@JsonProperty` meant to define here? I'm not sure it even makes sense on a controller. Did you want to define the controller returns Json? You probably want to look at the `consumes` and `produces` attributes of `@RequestMapping()`.

Comment: quite right @Thomas. renoved.

Comment: Have you setup the accept headers through some configuration or through filters? Your mock servlet response returning accept headers which doesn't contain `application/json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite my, admittedly false, belief that this is taken care of by the @SpringBootTest annotation; I took advice found in another question, and added @EnableWebMvc at class level for my test, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to your RequestMapping

Comment: I have edited my question to show the response I received when I added your suggestion to the RequestMapping

Comment: @HellishHeat can you check what's being received? because in the request I can see Body = <no character encoding set>

Comment: It is not going into my controller method, response is 415.

Comment: ok, I get that...but can you check/provide the request body that's being sent?

also, just a fyi, in the controller you're trying to receive object SearchRequest autoCompleteSearchrequest, but that's not even used in the method...is that ok?